# is it possible to make plots in iOS5 from a Matlab .mat data file using CorePlot 0.9?

Tags: matlab, core-plot

I'm developing an application for iPad and I'll be interested in using CorePlot for my project.

As I'm far from an experienced programmer (been using Xcode and ObjC since early October) I wanted to ask if with CorePlot was it possible to plot a graph from a .mat file (Matlab). In my project data is stored in a matrix inside the .mat file

thank you!